# Proof verification: $|x-y|<ε\Leftrightarrow y-ε<x<y+ε$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is the Following Proof Correct?

> Let $x,y$ be real numbers and let $ε>0$ be a positive real. Show that $|x-y|<ε$ if and only if $y-ε<x<y+ε$.

*Proof.* Assume that $|x-y|<ε$, proposition **5.4.7** implies that either $x=y$, $x>y$ or $x<y$. In the first case the claim in question simplifies to $x-ε<x<x+ε$ which is evident when we consider that $ε>0$.

In the event $x>y$ it follows that $|x-y| = x-y<ε$ or equivalently $x<y+ε$. In addition since $y<x$ and $ε>0$ it follows that $y-ε<x$ in conclusion $y-ε<x<y+ε$. Likewise in the event where $x<y$ it follows that $|x-y| = y-x<ε$, adding $x-ε$ to both sides gives $y-ε<x$. In addition since $x<y$ and $ε>0$ it follows that $x<y+ε$ thus $y-ε < x < y+ε$.

Conversely assume that $y-ε<x<y+ε$ or equivalently $-ε<x-y<ε$. Again by trichotomy $x-y=0$ or $x-y<0$ or $x-y>0$. Addressing each case in order we see that if $x-y=0$ then $|x-y| = |0|=0<ε$. Now if $x-y<0$ then $|x-y| = -(x-y)=y-x$ but $-ε<x-y$ or equivalently $y-x<ε$, thus $|x-y|<ε$. Finally if $x-y>0$ then $|x-y| = x-y<ε$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: What is proposition 5.4.7? Which book? It might be good if you included more information.

Comment: My Apologies @MalayTheDynamo Its Analysis Volume One by Terrence Tao.

Comment: Looks great. Hopefully on your paper, you lay it out a bit more neatly.

Comment: @AtifFarooq I think you should ask yourself, "what is the simplest property or definition of absolute value that I'm allowed to use at this point?"  If it is, for example, $\;|z|<a \iff -a<z<a\;$, like one answer assumes, then you're already almost done.  But if it is "if $\;z \ge 0\;$ then $\;|z| = z\;$ and else $\;|z|=-z\;$, as another does, then the simplest proof is to do a case split: either $\;x-y \ge 0\;$ or not.  In both cases your proof can be a lot shorter and simpler than your current proof, making it a lot easier to verify for a reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think our OP Atif Farook's proof is OK, but following all the cases is a somewhat complex task.  If we define $\vert z \vert$ as

$z \ge 0 \Longrightarrow \vert z \vert = z, \tag 1$

$z < 0 \Longrightarrow \vert z \vert = -z, \tag 2$

which it seems he does, then we can proceed in shorter order with aid of the

***Lemma:***  $\vert z \vert < \epsilon \Longleftrightarrow -\epsilon < z < \epsilon$.

***Proof of Lemma:***

$\Longrightarrow:$  Given $\vert z \vert < \epsilon$, for $z \ge 0$, $-\epsilon < z = \vert z \vert < \epsilon$; for $z < 0$,
$-\epsilon < -z = \vert z \vert < \epsilon \Longrightarrow -\epsilon < z < \epsilon$; so in both cases, $-\epsilon < z < \epsilon$;

$\Longleftarrow:$ Given $-\epsilon < z < \epsilon$, we have $-\epsilon < -z < \epsilon$; so $z \ge 0 \Longrightarrow  \vert z \vert = z < \epsilon$; $z < 0 \Longrightarrow \vert z \vert = -z < \epsilon$.

***End:  Proof of Lemma.***

Now taking $z = x - y$ we see that

$\vert x - y \vert < \epsilon \Longleftrightarrow -\epsilon < x - y < \epsilon \Longleftrightarrow y - \epsilon < x < y + \epsilon. \tag 3$

As my colleague Mohammad Riazi-Kermani affirmed, the proof is shortened using properties of $\vert \cdot \vert$, one of which we developed here in the ***Lemma***.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I agree that this is a much more elegant and cleaner argument +1.

Answer (score 6):

Your proof could have been shorter using absolute value properties.

Note that $$ |x-y|<\epsilon\iff  -\epsilon < x-y < \epsilon\iff y-\epsilon < x < y+ \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\Leftrightarrow}
%$

You seem to be using the following definition or basic property of absolute value: if $\;z \ge 0\;$ then $\;|z| = z\;$ and else $\;|z|=-z\;$.

So a direct calculation could go as follows:
$$\calc
    |x-y| < \eps
\op\equiv\hints{case split on $\;x-y \ge 0\;$; use the above definition}\hints{-- we choose $\;(P \then \ldots) \land (\lnot P \then \ldots)\;$ over the}\hints{equivalent $\;(P \land \ldots) \lor (\lnot P \land \ldots)\;$ for the case split,}\hint{so that we have $\;\land\;$ at the outer level, as in our goal}
    (x-y \ge 0 \then x-y < \eps) \;\land\; (x-y < 0 \then -(x-y) < \eps)
\op\equiv\hint{logic: expand $\;\then\;$; isolate $\;x\;$, as in our goal}
    (x < y \lor x < y+\eps) \;\land\; (y \le x \lor y-\eps < x)
\op\equiv\hint{arithmetic: simplify using $\;\eps > 0\;$}
    x < y + \eps \;\land\;y - \eps < x 
\endcalc$$

$%
\endgroup
%$